# Excel - Checking if any day of specified month falls between a range of dates

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a worksheet with dates in columns A and B:

```
   col A   |    col B   |

2014-06-30 | 2014-10-31 | 
2014-01-21 | 2014-05-31 |
2012-03-07 | 2014-11-03 |
2013-02-05 | 2014-05-01 |
```

In column C I want to check if any day of specified month (i.e. June 2014) falls between dates form columns A and B:

```
   col A   |    col B   |   col C  |

2014-06-30 | 2014-10-31 |    yes   |
2014-01-21 | 2014-05-31 |    no    |
2012-03-07 | 2014-11-03 |    yes   |
2013-02-05 | 2014-05-01 |    no    |
```

Any ideas? (VBA or Excel formula)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There would only **not** be an overlap if the first day of that month is later than B, or if last day is before A, so this formula should work

`=IF(OR(A2>DATE(2014,6,30),B2<DATE(2014,6,1)),"no","yes")`

To shorten you can put the start and end dates of the reference period in two cells, e.g. `E1` and `F1` and then use this version:

`=IF(OR(A2>F$1,B2<E$1),"no","yes")`

Answer (score -1):

Assuming Excel knows that the first to columns are dates; lets say you put your "specified month" in column D, this is how you can compare it:

```
=IF(AND(D1>A1,D1<B1),"yes","no")
```

It would have to compare another date, like if you wanted to test July you would reference a cell with 7-1-2014

In order to be more specific you would probably want to use VBA and [date references](http://www.classanytime.com/mis333k/sjdatetime.html) to check.

Comment: Quote the OP: "In column C I want to check if any day of specified month (i.e. June 2014) " but he doesn't specify which month.